# What is the BNF for a regex (in order to write a full or partial parser)

Tags: regex, bnf

I am interested [in parsing regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429995/code-to-parse-capture-groups-in-regular-expressions-into-a-tree) (not to be confused with using regexes for parsing). Is there a BNF for Java 1.6 regexes (or other languages?)

[NOTE: There is a [similar older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265457/regex-grammar) which did not lead to an answer for Java.]

**EDIT** To explain why I need to do this. We are implementing a shallow parser for Natural language processing which first identifies and tags tokens. These are then further processed with a regex. I need to know what groups have been captured by the regex (the automaton only captures the last of each bracket) and I also want to annotate the regex with comments.

Comment: Why do you need to parse the regex?

Comment: Maybe he's implementing a regex engine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex Grammar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265457/regex-grammar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be an explicit regex according to SO replies.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265457/regex-grammar) they point to attempts at describing Perl's regexes in BNF:

http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/384/99-3/regexp-plg.html

http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/25718/fid/200

Comment: http://www.faqts.com/knowledge%5Fbase/view.phtml/aid/25718/fid/200 doesn't work for me

Comment: @Makach: Replace `%5F` with `_`. SO seems to replace that in URLs.

Comment: The faqts link appears to be dead. The sfu.ca link provides neither epsilon nor optional, and as such can't specify all regular languages let along something as complex as a perl regex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see one specifically for java 1.6; but here's a start that maybe you can build a complete BNF from:

http://www.users.pjwstk.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/wd/regexp.html#RegularExpressionBNF

...using the java 1.6 documentation for Pattern:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Also you should be aware, if you weren't already, that the JDK has support for regular expressions (see the Pattern class linked in this post) - be sure you aren't reinventing the wheel.